# Base64 element (from xml) too big to be stock in a string?

Tags: android, xml, string, base64

Below, the return of one of my webservice (it's a pdf in base64):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getVoucherResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mywebservice.com/">
         <voucher>JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwovT3V0bGluZXMgMiAwIFIKL1BhZ2Vz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[...]

tTpDkmdIevmFgJAzL3/SkhOYUnUaU6nrcEnoRkaIupXDwYdxF3W66KI97A/6L5OdNK346VQrjokV
HtWQG5KZuuqPs/k8BOzfQUNbhfP5DELiU8yh+WtPiIVN0ojVFY/TkBLCuVDAaKk16Ay9Cb6i194N
oJcIxTwbaAZFqeobdBfBLNliUVqOgzCOVlG8+fEmmM+D6Wy5xpNo4dlOmOT4UuV2xUItyRWxefbv
lYVUWb1wUMW05yzacZOyrCvwvV7mX/D2sqyvcJkdvGXbKijzHUrWyEqZ7Pcn2xZXcDIqT9saQl+P
77O2NYMW5utaXGnfVJHUha40LUAoLxyDBTcpZDkbIywrG+HKBkj5MlSHKquDFZZ9r/YJKw5nLvYF
6C2r5EKFLorDjlV0vO8Pm08uOF8gkw36A9z7Cf2KfoPv01ahEnoshfa1gJBgqkrCHI1S83Mq7Myt
x3rksR5aHK+0NscrumIklUeCQcIKYut+jcLbBZzdMNxMw9LBJl8YzGBQ3eALDDuGlYTcF0cVYB85
</voucher>
      </ns2:getVoucherResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I send my webservice request by a simple http protocol and i receive the response by the same way.
I tried to parse the xml response and stock the answer in a string but it seems that the answer is too big.

What is the best was to stock the element voucher and then decode the base64?

Any help is appreciated ;) !

Comment: Would you consider parsing the thing "manually" using a SAXParser?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Base64 library on android 2.2+ (api 8), but if you want your project is available for earlier versions, you can add the code android to library to your project, you have the source code of the library Base64.java:
http://hi-android.info/src/android/util/Base64.java.html

Comment: Actually, you should consider (by default) to include a copy of the Base64 utility - it's as usual a horribly kludge of an API that's hidden most of the useful parts required for stream decoding (e.g. the `Base64.Decoder/Encoder` or the ctor for `Base64OutputStream` that also does decoding instead of _just_ encoding).

Comment: Last week I had the same problem as you, and what I did was to include Base64.java file in my project, I have not had any problems (yet). In the file is already included Base64.java methods to decode/encode String/byte[]. What's Base64OutputStream have not seen any problem because Base64 not use this class.

Comment: The static methods exposed in the `android.util.Base64` class depend on two internal package-private stateful classes that can do chunk encoding and decoding - i.e. you do not have to load the entire Base64 encoded value into a String or byte array to decode it. The exposed constructors of the Base64OutputStream doesn't allow you to do decoding-on-the-fly, only encoding, which is kind of stupid, considering that Google hid the API for decoding in that particular class.